# Prevent join BigBlueButton meeting using iframe url

Tags: php, bigbluebutton

I used the BBB PHP api to create a meeting and join.
BBB hosted on separate server
iframe embed in our application. (application hosted another server)
iframe can be accessed by only authorized users in our application.

Issue is:-
I can go to the browser inspect element and copy the iframe url and paste it on another browser.
Currently I am able to join the same meeting from another device.
How can I prevent this?

Comment: I dont think you can avoid this, one approach is to follow bbb's reference application greenlight's approach where you redirect to the html5 client rather than display in an iframe. FYI redirect looks like `/bigbluebutton/api/enter?sessionToken=rytbsvkmue7yoxhb`, if you paste this is a browser you just get a bunch of meeting stats

Comment: I want to keep inside our application. if we redirect, it will change the url on address bar